# Summations of a summation without upper bound as a lemma

Tags: equations, symbols, lemma

So I have a paper I'm writing for a class that requires me to include a proof.  I have the proof all sorted out on paper but I'm having a very hard time figuring out where to begin in Latex.  I need to include the picture below as a lemma so it will appear in the equation listed in the code below.  I already have `\newtheorem{lemm}{Lemma}` at the top of my document.  Basically, if I can figure out how to code the equation from the image into Latex as a lemma, I think I'll have everything I need to code the rest of the proof.  I'm very new at Latex so this is a daunting task for me.  Any feedback or suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
\begin{lemm}  
A(x)B(x)=  
\end{lemm}
```

[image: Lemma]

Comment: I would recommend that you find a (not so) gentle introduction to LaTeX.  This example wouldn't have been too hard to do from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{lemm}{Lemma}
\begin{document}
\begin{lemm}
\[
A(x)B(x) = \sum_{k\ge0} \biggl( \sum_{i=0}^{k}a_ib_{k-i} \biggr) x^k
\]
\end{lemm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are a life saver!  Thank you very much!  I think I should be able to finish the proof from here.